# SQL Server 2005 Express won't uninstall

Tags: sql-server-2005, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall SQL Server 2005 Express from my machine. I think it got installed along with VS 2008, but I've never used it and now just want it gone.

I go through Add/Remove to uninstall and I get this:

[image: Component Selection page]

I check **Workstation Components** and click **Next**, bringing me here:

[image: Confirmation page]

I click **Finish** and things proceed, but the uninstaller closes so quickly that I can't get a screen snap.  SQL Server 2005 remains listed in Add/Remove, and in the Programs menu, and the directory structure and contents remain in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server.

I've been trying to get this thing uninstalled for a few hours now, and would appreciate any help!

Comment: had the same problem... I installed in English, but it was in OS language... now to uninstall it no idea how...